# reverse the text insertion in a JtextArea

Tags: java, swing, message

I Have a chat window on which I have a JTextField in which the user enters its message and a JtextArea in which the conversation is being displayed. The issue is that naturally the text is inserted from the top to the bottom of the JtextArea which will make the last messages invisible for the user unless he scrolls down, which is not cool. [image]

I have two solutions in mind : 
the first as the title says, is to reverse the text insertion making the most recent messages in the top. 
The second is to make the down scroll automatic so the user can see the last message without scrolling. 
Which one is more doable technically ?

Comment: Either is easy to do -- your choice.

Comment: Is that a TextArea??? Ewww! Here's something better: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/Quote.java